# How to get all arguments passed to function (vs. optional only $args)

Tags: powershell, arguments

$args returns only optional arguments. How can I get all function parameters?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

$args returns any *undeclared* parameters, not optional parameters.  So just don't declare parameters.

In PowerShell v2, you can use $PSBoundParameters to get all parameters in a structured way.

Comment: Would this behave in the same way as `$@` in bash?

Comment: (Technically `$@` without quotes is an error; you mean `"$@"`.)

Answer (score 40):

$PSBoundParameters gets you all the parameters that were "bound" along with the bound values in a hashtable, it doesn't get you the optional/extra arguments. That is what $args is for.  AFAICT the only way to get what you want is to combine the two:

```
$allArgs = $PsBoundParameters.Values + $args
```

Answer (score 0):

`$MyInvocation.Line` is also a good one to know.

But that will include the actual command as well.

Answer (score 0):

useful way to dynamically inspect and display the parameters of a function

```
Write-Host "Parameters and Default Values:"
foreach ($param in $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Parameters.keys) {
    Write-Host "${param}: $(Get-Variable -Name $param -ValueOnly -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)"
}
```

and params with  values only

```
Write-Host "Parameters and Default Values:"
foreach ($param in $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Parameters.keys) {
    $value = Get-Variable -Name $param -ValueOnly -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if (-not $null -eq [string]$value) {
        Write-Host "${param}: $value"
    }
}
```